# Regex for extracting the exception names

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to extract the exception name from the below sentences using regex pattern,

1. Error: MYTERA RuntimeException: No task output
2. Error: android.java.lang.NullPointerException.checked

I need the terms **RuntimeException** and **NullPointerException** with a single Regex pattern.

Comment: `\w+Exception`?

Comment: Thank you @RobbyCornelissen . I went off the hook, was thinking too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/soqraM/1) might help you to do so:

```
([A-Za-z]+Exception)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize your expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Performance

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = 'Error: android.java.lang.NullPointerException.checked';
 var regex = /(.*)\.([A-Za-z]+Exception)(.*)/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$2");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```